# Saving images from flash to server using PHP

Tags: php, apache-flex, flash, actionscript-3

I am trying to save some images from Flash to Php by sending a jpgstream, capturing it in php and pushing it to a file. Not sure what I am doing wrong here.

I am putting all the images I need into an array like so: (history is just where I am keeping all the image data)

```
for each($value in history)
            {

                var jpgSource:BitmapData = new BitmapData ($value.sourceImg.width, $value.sourceImg.height);
                jpgSource.draw($value.sourceImg);
                var encoder:JPEGEncoder = new JPEGEncoder(100);
                var jpgStream:ByteArray =  encoder.encode(jpgSource);
                var imgDetailArr:Array = new Array(jpgStream, $value.name);
                imgArr.push(imgDetailArr);



            }
```

And then i send that to PHP using a remote object and amfphp:

```
rmObj.saveUserImages( imgArr);
```

On the php side I am doing this:

```
function saveUserImages( $imgArr)
    {
        foreach($imgArr as $value)
        {


            ob_start();
            /* output image as JPEG */
            $image = imagecreatefromjpeg($value[0]);     
            header('Content-type: image/jpeg');
            imagejpeg( $image );
            /* save output as file */
            ob_flush();
            file_put_contents( "images", ob_get_contents() );


        }
    }
```

But this doesn't seem to do the trick. I have been going through a bunch of different tutes and code snippets, so maybe I just ogt something confused along the way.  I have done this before though and don't remember it being this difficult.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may be better off calling JS from Flash and pass a path to the file via AJAX. Then, use PHP to upload the files directly. PHP has support for file uploads from a hard drive.

**Edit:**

On second thought, try switching `ob_flush` with the line after it.  It looks like you are deleting your temporary data before saving it.

Comment: But these are images created in flash, I'm trying to push these images to a folder. Not sure what path I would use for the ajax if they aren't yet in a directory.

Answer (score 0):

im no expert on flash but this seems to be doing what you are looking for ... thoughts?

http://henryjones.us/articles/using-the-as3-jpeg-encoder

Comment: I am actually using the jpegencoder.. but I want to incorporate it with the flex remote object and amfphp, not as3 loaders. Having a little bit of a tough time doing that.